# How to create a Master/Slave relationship between Arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pointers, reference

I'm looking for a way to build a Master array that contains my 'real' objects, and a Slave array that contains references to a subset of objects contained in the Master Array such that any add/modify/delete operations to objects in the Master array would reflect in the child array(s).

The advantage I'm hoping to gain is that I'll only have to change my objects in the Master, and all the slave arrays will simply reflect those changes.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LaserDeathBlade/1rexz0k2/)

**working example: (modify)**

```
var master = [{a: "hello"}, {b:"world"}];
var slave = [master[0]]; //slave is a subset of master, containing only 1 element
master[0].a = "foo";
console.log(slave);

//Desired outcome: [{a:"foo"}]
//Actual outcome: [{a:"foo"}]
//This works!
```

**non-working example: (delete)**

```
var master = [{a:"hello"}, {b:"world"}];
var slave = [master[0]];
master.splice(0,1); //slave[0] is a reference to master[0], now it needs to be removed

console.log(slave);
//desired outcome: []
//actual outcome: [{a: "hello"}]
//boo, not working
```

Is this possible?

Comment: To clarify - am I correct in assuming that changes to the slave arrays should not impact the master array?

Comment: It might be possible, but if for whatever reason you need this in your code, you should probably rethink *why you would need this in the first place*.

Comment: @Shadow You are correct about the master/slave relationship, but for my purposes it's fine if the 'slave' arrays impact the master array because I completely avoid modifying slave arrays.

Comment: In that case, why not just have slave and master reference the same array? `var master = []; var slave = master;` Now, since master and slave are literally pointers to the same object, any change made in one will be also made to the other so to speak...

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified in the post, I made the edit now. The slave arrays won't be identical to the master array, I want them to be a subset of the master array. I'm using the term master/slave very loosely because I don't know of another term to describe this as.

Comment: slave will have to be smarter than just a plain old array. You could have slave have an attribute reference to the master `slave.master = master` and implement a method/function that returns slave objects from master if present.

Comment: This is bizarre as even if it did reference the master then the result would be  '[{b:"world"}]' NOT '[]'

Comment: @Fraser Obviously referencing the master isn't the only thing required to make it work.  As I said, you also need a method that filters from slave items not in master.

Comment: @DougCoburn - That isn't what I mean...don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your working example above works is because `slave[0]` is an alias of `master[0]`.
This line of code:

```
var master = [{a: "hello"}, {b:"world"}];
```

created three objects: an array object referenced by the name `master` and two unnamed objects `{a: "hello"}` and `{b: "world"}` which are referenced by the named object `master` as `master[0]` and `master[1]` respectively.

Then this line:

```
var slave = [master[0]];
```

created a new reference to the already existing object `{a: "hello"}`.  Now both `master[0]` and `slave[0]` reference the same object.  Note that there is no hidden link between the array objects `master` and `slave` here.

Now when you modify this object via one alias:

```
master[0].a = "foo";
```

Those changes are visible when reference by any other of it's aliases:

```
console.log(slave);
```

What happened in the non-working example is you deleted the copy of the reference in array `master` but left the copy in array `slave` untouched.  `slave` doesn't *see* changes to `master`

To get the behavior you desire, you will need to give slave a reference to the master array and use a getter method to retrieve the state so that when you request the state of slave, that method can discover which elements of it's subset are no longer valid.

Below is a possible implementation of that logic.

```js
function Slave(master, subset) {
  return {
    get: () => {
      let result = [];
      subset.forEach(e => {
        if (~master.indexOf(e)) result.push(e);
      });
      return result;
    },
  };
}

var master = [{a: "hello"}, {b:"world"}];
var slave = Slave(master, [master[0]]); //slave is a subset of master, containing only 1 element
master[0].a = "foo";

console.log('Desired outcome: [{"a":"foo"}]');
console.log('Actual outcome: ' + JSON.stringify(slave.get(), null, 0));

master.splice(0,1); //slave[0] is a reference to master[0], now it needs to be removed

console.log('Desired outcome: []');
console.log('Actual outcome: '+ JSON.stringify(slave.get(), null, 0));
```

In the above code, we capture the reference to `master` via closure and require the state of the slave to be computed on demand via a getter function.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Constructor instead:

```js
function MasterSlave(masterArray, slaveSubset){
  this.master = masterArray;
  this.subset = slaveSubset === undefined ? 0 : slaveSubset;
  this.slave = function(){
    return [this.master[this.subset]];
  }
}
var crazy = new MasterSlave([{a:'hello'}, {b:'world'}]);
crazy.master[0].a = 'foo';
console.log(crazy.slave());
crazy.master.splice(0, 1);
console.log(crazy.slave());
```

IE9+

```js
function MasterSlave(masterArray, slaveSubset){
  this.master = masterArray;
  this.subset = slaveSubset === undefined ? 0 : slaveSubset;
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'slave', {get:function(){
    return [this.master[this.subset]];
  }});
}
var crazy = new MasterSlave([{a:'hello'}, {b:'world'}]);
crazy.master[0].a = 'foo';
console.log(crazy.slave);
crazy.master.splice(0, 1);
console.log(crazy.slave);
```

Comment: As I was going to say in the comments to the question - if you reference master, then remove the first element, the result will be '{ "b": "world" }' - i.e by removing index 0 then index 1 becomes 0.